# How to Login the PL/SQL Developer UI via CommandLine with params?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm going to develop a program, in which I want to login the PL/SQL Developer UI via CommandLine with params.
I have tried many times but I can't get the result. So I come here to get some helps.
It cannot fill in the login form correctly when I use the command blew(in CMD):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer\plsqldev.exe" userid=root/123@localhost:1521/test
```

[image]
all the commands are filled in the 'Username' blank， the 'Password' and 'Database' blanks are empty.
[image]

Also, before the Oracle Logon appear, it says these:
[image]
I search the Internet but I can't find it.

Would you tell me how to achieve it, I express my appreciation of your help.

ps, the version information below:
[image]

Comment: As path contains spaces, try to enclose it into double quotes.

Comment: I used double quotes, and the program can open, but the params can't fill in the correct blank.

Comment: Shouldn't that backward slash you used be a **forward** slash? `:1521/test`

Comment: I input as you suggest:  root/123@127.0.0.1:1521\test . but it won't work T_T

Comment: Don't look at the mirror. I said FORWARD slash. You used a BACKWARD one again.

Comment: The screenshot and the text for your command line are different - can you confirm the screenshot version is what you actually tried? Also, can you log in normally via the Start menu/taskbar etc? Just to rule out installation issues.

Comment: sorry, someone changed my question text.I use the forward slash as the screenshot shows, I change it back. I'll rule out the installation issue first, thx~

Comment: There are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PL/SQL Developer, and they must use the corresponding 32-bit or 64-bit Oracle client. It looks like you have the 32-bit PL/SQL Developer. (You can tell which Oracle Client you have by starting SQL*Plus and looking for it in the Task Manager "Processes" tab.) The error message suggests this might be the issue. That's why I asked whether you can start it up and log in normally.